# Update a file in GitHub using a local file

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, pygithub

I am trying to write a script to update the contents of a file in a GitHub repo.
I have a `File.txt` that has the required data.

Here's the code I've written

```
from github import Github
g = Github(ACCESS_TOKEN)
repo = g.get_repo(REPO_NAME)
contents = repo.get_contents("GITHUB_FILE_PATH")
repo.update_file(contents.path, "COMMIT_MSG", "NEW_CONTENT", contents.sha, branch = BRANCH_NAME)
```

Is there a way I can pass `File.txt` as the `NEW_CONTENT` parameter so that the content of the github file is replaced by content of `File.txt`?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldnt just do a new commit?

Comment: @Craicerjack because I need to do this in hundreds of repos.

Comment: Sure, just read the contents of `File.txt` into a variable, and pass that as the new content parameter.

Comment: Do you still need help? If you've solved it feel free to place the answer